# Конструктор в Java

Tags: java

Читал про конструкторы в *Java* и на толкнулся на такой код :

```
 class A {
    A(int k) {super();}
}
class B extends A {
    B(int k) {super(k);}
```

Объясните, почему в классе `А` написали `super()` ? Ведь `super()` вызывает конструктор класса предка.

А что в этом случае вызывает `super()` в классе предке ? Конструктор чего ?

Answer (score 6):

этот код:

```
class A {
    A(int k) {super();}
}
class B extends A {
    B(int k) {super(k);}
}
```

абсолютно идентичен этому (потому что все наследуются от Object):

```
class A extends Object {
    A(int k) {super();}
}
class B extends A {
    B(int k) {super(k);}
}
```

и абсолютно идентично этому:

```
class A {
    A(int k) {}
}
class B extends A {
    B(int k) {super(k);}
}
```

потому что при наследовании классы неявно вызывают конструктор супер класса (если у него есть конструктор без параметров)

почему написали - видимо для того чтоб подчеркнуть что у класса А тоже есть суперкласс

Answer (score 4):

Я могу ошибаться, но любой объект имеет суперклассом класс Object. А значит super() в классе А вызывает его конструктор. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Comment: Все именно так

Comment: public class A {
   public A()
    {

    }
}
class B extends A {
    public B (int i){

    }
}
Появился еще вопрос. А почему этот код работает. Ведь по сути конструктор в классе А должен быть public A(int i) ?

Comment: на самом деле не должен быть. Вы наследуете класс, но не обращаетесь к конструктора предка (не используете super()). Соответственно конструктор класса В отличается от конструктора класса А.

Comment: но на удивление работает. я собственно и сам не могу понять в чем соль

Comment: нет-нет, Вы неправильно меня поняли. Здесь всё написано правильно. Конструктор класса В не относится к конструктору класса А. Он здесь свой.

Comment: но ведь при наследовании мы иерархии и с начала обращаемся к конструктору предка ? или я не так понял ?

Comment: не обязательно обращаться к конструктору предка.

Comment: а разве при наследовании класс В неявно не вызывает конструктор супер класса А ?

Comment: @Drylozav вызывает, но если нет его явного вызова вызывается конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров)

Answer (score 1):

При компиляции добавляется "extends java.lang.Object" тем классам, которые ни от кого не наследуются, поэтому все классы в итоге наследники Object.

Также, первой строкой в конструкторе должен быть либо вызов конструктора предка super(...), либо другой конструктор этого класса через this(...). Если этой строки нет, то при компиляции добавляется вызов конструктора предка без параметров - super().

Если у класса нет ни одного конструктора, то при компиляции добавляется конструктор по умолчанию - без параметров, с пустым телом (если не считать super()).

> А почему этот код работает. Ведь по сути конструктор в классе А должен
>   быть public A(int i)

Не должен, конструкторы не наследуются.

Answer (score 0):

Да, там будет обращение к **Object** предку. Кстати не хорошо объявлять конструктор закрытым(по-умолчанию), если только вы не используете шаблон фабричный метод или синглтон!